# What's the difference between "agradezco" and "gracias"?

Tags: vocabulario, cortesía, diferencias-entre-palabras

What's the difference between "[agradezco](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/agradezco)" (from the verb 'agradecer') and "[gracias](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/gracias)"? Both mean "Thank you" but when would you use one over the other? Please explain making reference to the below examples:

Example 1:

> **Gracias** por su gentileza.
>   <sub>(Thanks, that’s nice of you)</sub>

Example 2:

> **Gracias**, es muy fácil. Voy mañana con mi familia.
>   <sub>(Thanks, that’s very easy. I’m going tomorrow with my family.)</sub>

Example 3:

> Te **agradezco** mucho la invitación, pero…
>   <sub>Thanks very much the invitation, but…</sub>

Example 4:

> Le **agradezco** mucho.
>   <sub>Thank you very much</sub>

Example 5:

> Muchas **gracias**.
>   <sub>Thank you very much</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, "agradecer" is a verb, whereas "gracias" is just a noun used as an idiom itself.

You use "gracias" in the same way you use "thank you".

On the other hand, "Le agradezco que..." means kind of `I am grateful that...`. You can also use `estoy agradecido`, which would be a more literal translation of "I'm grateful".